# Как объединить набор неотсортированных отрезков в многоугольники за время не более O(n)?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

[image]

Есть набор неотсортированных отрезков lineSegments.

```
std::vector<std::array<glm::vec3, 2>> lineSegments.
lineSegments = {P1P2, A3A2, P2P3, A4A5 ...} (P1P2 = {{x, y, z}, {x, y, z}})
```

Как мне их отсортировать так, чтоб получились наборы вершин `P1-P2-...-Р8` и `А1-А2-...-А8`:
`std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>> polygons` за О(n) или быстрее?

Вот алгорит, который сделал я, но здесь O(n^2):

```
void orderVertices(std::vector<std::vector<Vec>>& polygons)
{
    while (lineSegments.size() != 0)
    {
        std::vector<Vec> polygon;
        polygon.push_back(lineSegments.front()[0]);
        polygon.push_back(lineSegments.front()[1]);
        lineSegments.erase(lineSegments.begin());
        while (1)
        {
            bool isFound = false;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < lineSegments.size(); j++)
            {
                if (compareWithPrecision(polygon.back(), lineSegments[j][0]))
                {
                    isFound = true;
                    polygon.push_back(lineSegments[j][1]);
                    lineSegments.erase(lineSegments.begin() + j);
                    break;
                }
                else if (compareWithPrecision(polygon.back(), lineSegments[j][1]))
                {
                    isFound = true;
                    polygon.push_back(lineSegments[j][0]);
                    lineSegments.erase(lineSegments.begin() + j);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isFound)
            {
                polygon.pop_back();
                polygons.push_back(polygon);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример работы программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вход:

```
std::vector<std::array<glm::vec3, 2>> lineSegments = {
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}},
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}},
    {{1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}},
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}}
};
```

Выход:

```
std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>> polygons = {
   {
     {-1, 1, 0},
     {1, 1, 0},
     {1, -1, 0},
     {-1, -1, 0}
   }
}
```

Comment: За О(n) еще никому ничего отсортировать не удавалось.

Comment: ну, в некоторых случаях можно. А вот быстрее - вот это вряд ли. Как минимум по всем элементам нужно пройтись.

Comment: @user7860670, в данном случае никак невозможно сделать O(n)?

Comment: @KoVadim, могли бы вы подсказать как за O(n) сделать?

Comment: Ненужно именно сортировать. Нужно уметь находить отрезок, исходящий из заданной точки за O(1). - Используйте хеш-таблицу.

Comment: я имел ввиду, что просто сортировку можно сделать за O(n) (если это массив char,  к примеру).

Comment: @Chorkov могли бы вы подробнее описать как это сделать, пожалуйста?

Comment: Хеш-таблица: ключ - вершина, значение - список вершин - соседей ключа. Список будет длиной два. То что получилось - граф представленный списками смежности. Его компоненты связности - циклы, то есть многоугольники.

Comment: это если бы был классический многоугольник. Если же дело обстоит так, как у автора на рисунке, то считать будет чуточку сложнее

Comment: @KoVadim, не понятно. Что может быть кроме циклов в графе?

Comment: отрезки могут пересекаться не концами, а немножко ближе к центру.

Comment: `P3` обозначает точку пересчения двух отрезков, ничего другого. Вас ввела в заблуждение картинка, @KoVadim. На случай если вы правы а я ошибаюсь остаётся ещё алгоритм Бентли-Оттмана. За `NlogN` можно восстановить граф и в нём компоненты связности.

Comment: @ANGRYSHARK, пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос конкретный пример входа и выхода.

Comment: @KoVadim, вызовы `compareWithPrecision` намекают что концы отрезков совпадают. То есть, это просто графовая задача, без геометрии.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy добавил

Comment: ну, если они совпадают, а ещё и целочисленные, тогда действительно, простенький хеш решает все.

Comment: @KoVadim `Vec{ double x, y, z }`

Comment: Тип не важен если и одной и той же вершины координаты вписаны всегда одинаково. Тогда равенство будет работать и хеш посчитается одинаковый.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я использую эпсилон для равенства. eps = 0.1*10^-14

Comment: В данном случае использование эпсилон только портит алгоритм. Если все данные из одного источника, то используйте равенство.

Comment: сравнивание вещественных чисел на равенство - очень скользкий лед. Чуточку не так и все...

Comment: @KoVadim , сравнение с эпсилон - не менее скользкий лёд. Но у всех в головах "поставлю эпсилон - решу все проблемы". Конкретно в этой задаче эпсилон порождает больше проблем чем решает.

Comment: я абсолютно согласен с этим. Поэтому я и сказал выше - если числа целые - то проблем нет. А с вещественными всегда есть "особенности".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, можно у вас взять почту или телеграмм? Здесь не удобно. Я просто совершенно не пойму как мне это реализовать через хэш

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этой задаче нет геометрии, только графы. Из списка рёбер нужно составить граф рёбер, обойти его поиском в глубину. Каждая компонента связности - многоугольник.

Граф представлен как [список смежности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Компоненты связности ищутся рекурсивным [поиском в глубину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83).

С++ добавляет сложности, так требуется определить хеш-функцию для вектора из трёх вещественных значений. Реализация заимствована из [boost.hash_combine](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine).

Весь алгоритм выполняется за линейное время от числа вершин многоугольников.

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Iglm restore-polygons.cpp

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>

using point_t = glm::vec3;
using segment_t = std::array<point_t, 2>;

void hash_combine(size_t& seed, size_t hash_value) {
    seed ^= hash_value + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}

struct hash_t {
    std::size_t operator()(const point_t& p) const {
        std::size_t seed = std::hash<decltype(p.x)>{}(p.x);
        hash_combine(seed, std::hash<decltype(p.y)>{}(p.y));
        hash_combine(seed, std::hash<decltype(p.z)>{}(p.z));
        return seed;
    }
};

std::vector<segment_t> read_segments() {
    std::vector<segment_t> segments;
    point_t p1;
    point_t p2;
    while (std::cin >> p1.x >> p1.y >> p1.z >> p2.x >> p2.y >> p2.z) {
        segments.push_back({p1, p2});
    }
    return segments;
}

using graph_t = std::unordered_map<point_t, std::vector<point_t>, hash_t>;
using set_t = std::unordered_set<point_t, hash_t>;

void restore_polygon(const graph_t& graph, const point_t& point, set_t& visited,
                     std::vector<point_t>& polygon) {
    if (visited.find(point) == visited.end()) {
        visited.insert(point);
        polygon.push_back(point);
        for (const point_t& q : graph.find(point)->second) {
            restore_polygon(graph, q, visited, polygon);
        }
    }
}

void restore_polygons(const std::vector<segment_t>& segments,
                      std::vector<std::vector<point_t>>& polygons) {
    graph_t graph;
    for (const segment_t &s : segments) {
        graph[s[0]].push_back(s[1]);
        graph[s[1]].push_back(s[0]);
    }

    set_t visited;
    for (const auto& it : graph) {
        if (visited.find(it.first) == visited.end()) {
            polygons.push_back(std::vector<point_t>());
            restore_polygon(graph, it.first, visited, polygons.back());
        }
    }
}

void print_polygons(const std::vector<std::vector<point_t>>& polygons) {
    for (const std::vector<point_t>& polygon : polygons) {
        bool first = true;
        for (const point_t& p : polygon) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                std::cout << ", ";
            }
            std::cout << '(' << p.x << ", " << p.y << ", " << p.z << ')';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<segment_t> segments = read_segments();
    std::vector<std::vector<point_t>> polygons;
    restore_polygons(segments, polygons);
    print_polygons(polygons);
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Iglm restore-polygons.cpp
>
> $ cat segments 
>  1  1  0      1 -1  0
>  1  1 10      1 -1 10
> -1  1  0      1  1  0
> -1  1  0     -1 -1  0
> -1  1 10      1  1 10
> -1  1 10     -1 -1 10
> -1 -1  0      1 -1  0
> -1 -1 10      1 -1 10
>
> $ ./a.out < segments 
> (-1, -1, 0), (-1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, -1, 0)
> (-1, 1, 10), (1, 1, 10), (1, -1, 10), (-1, -1, 10)
> ```

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что если координаты будут в double, то возможны неточности?

Comment: Нет, если координаты просто скопированы (что нормально). Да, если для разных отрезков одна и та же вершина вычислена разными способами (что странно). Во втором случае надо провести кластеризацию. Кластеризация для разумных данных делается также за линейное время.

Comment: А как можно справиться с проблемой, что два многоугольника могут соприкасаться точкой\ами?

Comment: Да, можно. Ваша задача - частный случай такой: восстановить грани [ППЛГ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_straight-line_graph) по набору вершин и рёбер. Эта задача разрешима за линейное время.

Comment: Я же правильно понимаю, что для этого нужно реализовывать структуру half-edge?

Comment: Да, так и есть.